# Humanity vs society

Tags: word-choice, word-usage

When should I use each term?

Defintions (Vocabulary.com):

> The noun society refers to people living in social order. Unless you are a reclusive person, you are a part of society in some way or another.

vs

> Humanity is the human race, which includes everyone on Earth. It’s also a word for the qualities that make us human, such as the ability to love and have compassion, be creative, and not be a robot or alien.

From those definitions there is a pretty clear distinction.

**But in certain situations I am unsure which word to use. E.g. is it better to say “How will it effect society?" vs "How will it effect humanity"?**

Comment: Note that both terms have multiple meanings, depending both on immediate context and on the broader context of the political views of author and reader.  "Society" may mean the broad social order, or it may mean the hoity-toity upper crust.  Similarly, "humanity" may refer, in a color-blind fashion, to all humans, or it may be used to refer to those too lowly to be counted as "society".  And other variations.

Comment: You need *affect*, not *effect*.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you ask "How will X affect society", you are really asking how will X affect the way in which we interact with one another in the short term, whether it is within a particular social class, a nation, or even everyone.

When you ask "How will X affect humanity", you are asking how will X affect the fundamental nature of the human race in the long term, or even its very existence.

So:

- How will the Internet affect society?
- How will wearable computers affect society?
- How will cheap air travel affect society?

And:

- How will evolution affect humanity?
- How will global warming affect humanity?
- How will nuclear weapons affect humanity?

Of course, the Internet may well affect humanity in the long term, and nuclear weapons would almost certainly affect society in the short term, if they are ever used.